# Path to image within multiple directories

Tags: html, css, wordpress, path

I'm having problems linking to an image from a file in a subdirectory.

File structure is something like this:

..main-theme/parts/shared/**header.php**

..main-theme/images/**logo.png**

Within *header.php* I want to link to the *logo.png* image

```
<img src="images/logo.png"/>
```

I've tried every option I can think of of ../ that would make sense to climb from header.php but cannot work out what I should be doing as they always jump too high up into directories above *main-theme*

Comment: Have you tried using absolute paths for the image?

Comment: @JosefE. I'd prefer to not use an absolute path if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img src="../../images/logo.png"/>
```

Edit, since you mentioned that you are using WordPress:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/logo.png"/>
```

I believe that is the correct way to handle this within WordPress. It has the benefits of using an absolute path, but will automatically adjust when you move the project from localhost to a live domain.

Comment: This goes too high, but it's what I thought as well. It goes to http://localhost/images/logo.png (I'm working on a local wordpress build) which is the top directory of the site.

Comment: Ah, you should've mentioned that you were using WordPress. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Added WordPress-specific answer